# Validate email local component

Tags: python, regex, django, email-validation

I'm writing a registration form that only needs to accept the local component of a desired email address. The domain component is fixed to the site. I am attempting to validate it by selectively copying from `validators.validate_email` which Django provides for `EmailField`:

```
email_re = re.compile(
    r"(^[-!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}|~0-9A-Z]+(\.[-!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}|~0-9A-Z]+)*"  # dot-atom
    # quoted-string, see also http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.2.5
    r'|^"([\001-\010\013\014\016-\037!#-\[\]-\177]|\\[\001-\011\013\014\016-\177])*"'
    r')@((?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}\.?$)'  # domain
    r'|\[(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\]$', re.IGNORECASE)  # literal form, ipv4 address (SMTP 4.1.3)
validate_email = EmailValidator(email_re, _(u'Enter a valid e-mail address.'), 'invalid')
```

Following is my code. My main issue is that I'm unable to adapt the regex. At this point I'm only testing it in a regex tester at http://www.pythonregex.com/ however it's failing:

```
^([-!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}|~0-9A-Z]+(\.[-!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}|~0-9A-Z]+)*)$
```

This seems to be passing undesirable characters such as `?`

The entire code for my Field, which is not necessarily relevant at this stage but I wouldn't mind some comment on it would be:

```
class LocalEmailField(CharField):    
    email_local_re = re.compile(r"^([-!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}|~0-9A-Z]+(\.[-!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}|~0-9A-Z]+)*)$", re.IGNORECASE)
    validate_email_local = RegexValidator(email_re, (u'Enter a valid e-mail username.'), 'invalid')
    default_validators = [validate_email_local]
```

EDIT: To clarify, the user is only entering the text BEFORE the `@`, hence why I have no need to validate the `@domain.com` in the validator.

EDIT 2: So the form field and label will look like this:

Desired Email Address: [---type-able area---] @domain.com

Comment: Why don't you validate the email normally and then check if `email.endswith('@domain.com')`?

Comment: The user does not enter the @domain.com, that will be set as a label after the field in the form. The user is only to enter the first part of the email field, before the @

Comment: so basically `"[^@]*"` ?

Comment: I've obviously written my question badly, although I'm not sure how to improve it. The user at no point enters the text `@domain.com`, they only enter the username for the email.

Comment: you expliocitly allow '?' in that regex (are you sure that ? is not a valid part of the username portion of the email ... I think the rules are pretty loose..)

Answer (score 2):

You say "undesirable characters such as `?`", but I think you're mistaken about what characters are desirable. The original regex allows question marks.

Note that you can also define your own validator that doesn't use a massive regex, and have some chance of decoding the logic later.

Comment: valid user portion of email is pretty open ... I agree with the other answer that a regex probably is not appropriate... and certainly not a crazy big one

Comment: Since this is for email account creation, perhaps we can simply restrict the allowed characters more than the specification allows and then write a simpler validator. Also, d'oh!

Answer (score 1):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think, “I know, I’ll use
> regular expressions.” Now they have two problems. - [Jamie
> Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Checking via regex is an exercise in wasting your time. The best way is to attempt delivery; this way not only can you verify the email address, but also if the mailbox is actually active and can receive emails.

Otherwise you'll end up in an every-expanding regular expression that can't possibly hope to match all the [rules](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822).

`"Haha boo hoo woo woo!"@foo.com` is a valid address, so is `qwerterukeriouo@gmail.com`

Instead, offer the almost-standard *"Please click on the link in the email we sent to blahblah@goo.com to verify your address."* approach.

If you want to *create* email addresses, then you can write your own rules on what can be a part of the email component; and they can be a subset of the official allowed chars in the RFC.

For example, a conservative rule (that doesn't use regular expressions):

```
allowed_chars = [string.digits+string.letters+'-']

if len([x in user_input if x not in allowed_chars]):
   print 'Sorry, invalid characters'
else:
   if user_input[0] in string.digits+'-':
      print 'Cannot start with a number or `-`'
   else:
      if check_if_already_exists(user_input):
         print 'Sorry, already taken'
      else:
         print 'Congratulations!'
```

Comment: This is for creation of an email account, not for verification

Comment: then you can write your own rules about what is not allowed in a nice short easy regex... no need for that monster...

Comment: Yes I think that's the way to go, so many of those characters we could justifiably deny in the name of simplicity.

Comment: If that's the case, then simply `valid_chars = [string.letters+string.digits+'-']` and then search against that.

Comment: or probably better `invalid_chars_re = "[^?@#]*"` and just disallow specific chars rather than allowing a whole bunch...

Answer (score 1):

I'm still new to Django and Python, but why reinvent the wheel and maintain your own regex? If, apart from wanting users to enter only the local portion of their email address, you're happy with Django's built-in `EmailField`, you can subclass it quite easily and tweak the validation logic a bit:

```
DOMAIN_NAME = u'foo.com'


class LocalEmailField(models.EmailField):
    def clean(local_part):
        whole_address = '%s@%s' % (local_part, DOMAIN_NAME)
        clean_address = super(LocalEmailField, self).clean(whole_address)
        # Can do more checking here if necessary
        clean_local, at_sign, clean_domain = clean_address.rpartition('@')
        return clean_local
```

Have you looked at the documentation for [Form and Field Validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation) and the [.clean() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.clean)?

Comment: It seems many people are missing the requirement of the custom Field, that is, it is only for inputting the username section of the desired email address, for instance in, `USER@DOMAIN.COM`, the user would only enter `USER`. You're right though I should look into the field validation and get my head around the clean method more :)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something important, this should meet your requirements exactly. Rather than jumping through hoops to define exactly what constitutes a valid username, though, it takes the (to me) simpler approach of accepting ``USER`` as form input, appending ``@DOMAIN.COM``, validating the whole address using Django's built-in fields, and then returning ``USER``.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it 100% correctly with regex, you need to use an engine with some form of extended regex which allow matching nested parentheses.

Python's default engine does not allow this, so you're better off compromising with a very simple (permissive) regex.

Comment: regex by definition cant match nested anything... you would need a stack for that(or some form of memory) ... is there any python regex module that can match nested items?

Comment: Do you really need to match up parentheses to know if it's a valid address?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Yes, by 'extended regex' I'm referring to .NET or Perl-like engines that allow you to do this. I'm not sure if there's a PCRE-like interface for Python regex?

Comment: OK I just wasnt aware of any and like to stay on top of stuff like that :)